# Jquery No Conflict - Onclick Functions - Multiple Frameworks

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick, mootools

I have multiple JS Frameworks running and some `onClick="changeText()"` with the content just changing the elements text. In my script I have

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     function changeText(){
         $('#test').text('Hello World!');
     }
});
```

I believe that the `Jquery.ready` function is throwing it all off. In my debugger it is telling me that it cannot find my `changeText()` function, which the script is 100% loading in (I can view via view:source -> js link). Also if it makes a difference I'm running Joomla 1.5 with Mootools being loaded in as my other framework.

I also know the functions are 100% right because I can run them normally in a standard html page without the Jquery.ready function.

Is there a way to specify what file to call this from or 'hacky' way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries),

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

immediately after your jquery script tag will change the jQuery variable to $j

Answer (score 3):

you can wrap `jQuery` in a function. by the way, `$` is just an alias for `jQuery` which is the actual namespace of jQuery. all in all, it looks like this:

```
(function($){
   $(function(){

       //do regular jQuery as needed

       function changeText(){                //your function
           $('#test').text('Hello World!');
       }

       $('element').on('click',function(){   //onclick handler
           changeText();
       });

   });
}(jQuery));
```

---

as @ThiefMaster commented, you already used `jQuery` and provided `$` so you may discard my wrapping.

and to add, inline events like `<button onclick="doSomething()">` only trigger events that are on the global namespace. once you wrap the function in jQuery, it's not part of the global namespace anymore. it's better you attach event handlers using JS instead, from within the wrapped code.

Comment: O.K. but when I call my function, how will it know to look into jquery?

Comment: it's advised that you use event attachments instead of inline javascript to handle your events. also, you can't use inline events since your functions are enclosed in functions like the `ready()`. they are not anymore in the global scope. i've updated my answer to accomodate.

Comment: He already does the wrapping. The DOM ready event already passes the jQuery object so it can be used to map $ to jQuery inside the function - no need for another function around it. All he needs to do is making the function global (or as you suggested, add the event using javascript instead of using inline events)

Answer (score 0):

The best option is not using inline events at all - use `$('selector').on('click', function() { ... })` instead.

If you cannot do that for some reason, you can still use inline events. However, since you are defining your functions inside another function, you need to make them global. You do so by adding them to the `window` object which is the *global object* in a browser environment:

```
window.changeText = function() {
    // ...
};
```